# WiX build warning: The Media table has no entries

Tags: wix, windows-installer, votive

I'm trying to create a simple installer for a .net application in WiX. I installed Votive and am using the basic template wxs file it creates. When I compile it I get `warning LGHT1076: ICE71: The Media table has no entries.`

Also when I run the installer it starts and disappears during installation and there is no entry in the Add/Remove Programs app.

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="26d654fe-af0f-4b48-8993-8e249597a130" 
       Name="Minefold" 
       Language="1033" 
       Version="0.0.0.1" 
       Manufacturer="Minefold" 
       UpgradeCode="6aad5a10-cbbe-472b-87fc-0813fb450836">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Minefold" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
         <Component Id="ProductComponent">
     <File Source="C:\code\Minefold\Minefold\bin\Debug\Minefold.exe" Id="Minefold.exe"  />
         </Component> 
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
  <Feature Id="Application" Title="Minefold" Level="1">
    <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponent" />
  </Feature>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a Feature with a ComponentGroupRef to your Product. As written, nothing connects the Product with the content in the Fragments.